# Proper way to have polymorphism with composition instead of inheritance in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, polymorphism, composition, review

While working on a project I got stuck in my design while using inheritance. Now I try to get rid of it and instead use composition since that seems to be the appropriate solution to my problem. However, I need polymorfisme and I'm not sure if I implemented my composition in the right way.

Could someone have a look at my code below? In the last three lines I want all the animals to walk, but only if they have the ability to walk. Is it good practice to first check if an object has a certain attribute (in this case 'legs') before calling a function on this attribute? I'm just curious if this is a proper way to do this or if there is a better way.

```
class Animal:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def make_sound(self):
        print("silence...")


class Wings:

    def flap(self):
        print("Wings are flapping")


class Legs:

    def walk(self):
        print("Legs are walking")


class Bird:

    def __init__(self):
        self.animal = Animal("Bird")
        self.wings = Wings()

    def make_sound(self):
        print(f"{self.animal.name} is Singing!")


class Dog:

    def __init__(self):
        self.animal = Animal("Dog")
        self.legs = Legs()

    def make_sound(self):
        print(f"{self.animal.name} is Barking")


class Cat:

    def __init__(self):
        self.animal = Animal("Cat")
        self.legs = Legs()

    def make_sound(self):
        print(f"{self.animal.name} is Meowing!")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    animals = list()

    animals.append(Bird())
    animals.append(Dog())
    animals.append(Cat())

    for animal in animals:
        animal.make_sound()

    for animal in animals:
        if hasattr(animal, 'legs'):
            animal.legs.walk()
```

Answer (score 3):

You've been going a bit over the top actually xD

Inheritance describes a "is a" relationship, composition describes a "has a" relationship. So in your case, using composition for attributes like wings and legs makes perfect sense, but Bird, Cat and Dog ARE animals - they don't "have" an animal (well, they all have fleas but that's another topic) - so they should inherit from `Animal`.

Also, most birds have legs too AFAICT, and quite a few actually don't fly at all (but some use them to swim, and do so very efficiently) ;-)

> Is it good practice to first check if an object has a certain attribute (in this case 'legs') before calling a function on this attribute?

Depends on the context, really. As a general rule, no, it's not considered good practice (cf "tell don't ask" and "law of demeter"), but there are cases where it's legitimate. Also, the "good" design also depends on the problem to solve, and we here reach the limit of toy examples that are never representative of real-life use cases.

Theoretically, composition/delegation should be transparent to the client code, so you should just call `whatever_animal.walk()` and be done with it. Now you (as "the client code") might want to know the animal cannot walk, in which case non-walking animal should raise an exception when tolds to walk... It also means that `Animal` must have a default implementation for all possible "actions", and that the client code must be prepared for "UnsupportedAction" (or however you want to name them) exceptions.

wrt/ implementation, making the delegation transparent can be as simple as using `__getattr__()`, ie:

```
class UnsupportedAction(LookupError):
    pass

class Animal(object):
    _attributes = ()

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def make_sound(self):
        print("silence...")

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        for att in self._attributes:
            if hasattr(att, name):
                return getattr(att, name)
        else:
            raise UnsupportedAction("{} doesn't know how to {}".format(type(self), name))



class Dog(Animal):
    _attributes = (Legs(), )


class Bird(Animal):
    _attributes = (Legs(), Wings())
```

The nice point with this solution is that it's dead simple and very dynamic. The less nice point is that it's neither inspectable nor explicit.

Another solution is explicit delegation:

```
class UnsupportedAction(LookupError):
    pass

class Animal(object):
    _attributes = ()

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def make_sound(self):
        print("silence...")


    def walk(self):
        return self._resolve_action("walk")

    def fly(self):
        return self._resolve_action("walk")

    # etc            

    def _resolve_action(self, name):
        for att in self._attributes:
            if hasattr(att, name):
                return getattr(att, name)
        else:
            raise UnsupportedAction("{} doesn't know how to {}".format(type(self), name))
```

which is quite more verbose, much less dynamic, but much move obvious, documented, readable and inspectable.

In the above example, you could actually factor out the redundant code with a custom descriptor:

```
class Action(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, obj, cls):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        return obj._resolve_action(self.name)

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        raise AttributeError("Attribute is readonly")


class Animal(object):
    _attributes = ()

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def make_sound(self):
        print("silence...")

    walk = Action("walk")
    fly = Action("fly")

    # etc
```

But once again, none of this makes sense without a real problem to solve, which usually defines the proper solution.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate reply! It made me rethink my design and do some further research. You are absolutely right about the "is a" relationship. In this example the name "AnimalBehaviour" would maybe have been better then "Animal" in order to avoid inheritance.